# В чем отличие между <T> и <T extends someClass>?

Tags: java

Предположим, что есть класс:

```
public class TOP <T extends TOP> {
  private T element;
  public TOP <T> set (T element) {
     this.element = element;
     return this;
  }
  public T get () {
     return element;
   }
}
```

И класс наследник

```
public class A extends TOP <A> {
  // some code;
}
```

И вот в чем загвоздка, если я пишу такой код

```
public class TOP <T> {
  private T element;
  public TOP <T> set (T element) {
     this.element = element;
     return this;
  }
  public T get () {
     return element;
   }
}
```

И класс наследник

```
public class A extends TOP <A> {
  // some code
}
```

Они работают аналогично. В чем разница? Желательно на примерах :)

Comment: Ну положим во втором случае можно положить любой тип.... я могу написать так `TOP<String> twert = new TOP<>();`,  а могу `TOP<Integer> twert = new TOP<>();`, а могу `TOP<MySuperPuperClass> twert = new TOP<>();` ........в первом можно создать объекты только типа `TOP`...но наследование  у тебя какое-то странное

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно:) Код из учебника Thinking in Java, 4th edition :)

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, насколько ответ относится к вопросу, но, мне кажется, он будет полезен.

Предположим, у нас есть базовый класс и его наследник:

```
public class Base {
    int propertyBase;
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    int propertyDerived;
}
```

В каждом из классов есть по свойству. Мы можем написать сеттеры для этих свойств:

```
public class Base {
    int propertyBase;

    public Base setPropertyBase(int propertyBase) {
        this.propertyBase = propertyBase;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    int propertyDerived;

    public Derived setPropertyDerived(int propertyDerived) {
        this.propertyDerived = propertyDerived;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Теперь, чтобы в одну строчку создать новый экземпляр класса `Derived`, с инициализацией обоих свойств, нужно написать что-то вроде

```
Derived derived = new Derived()
        .setPropertyDerived(77)
        .setPropertyBase(77);
```

Но есть одна проблема — этот код не скомпилируется, так как возвращаемый тип метода `setPropertyBase` равен `Base` — не может быть неявно преобразован к `Derived`.

Разумеется, мы не хотим писать явных кастов. Таким образом, наиболее модный способ — параметризовать класс `Base` шаблонным параметром, который будет «равен» классу-наследнику. Тогда мы сможем изменить метод `setPropertyBase`, чтобы его возвращаемый тип был равен классу-наследнику.

```
public class Base<T extends Base> {
    int propertyBase;

    public T setPropertyBase(int propertyBase) {
        this.propertyBase = propertyBase;
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base<Derived> {
    int propertyDerived;

    public Derived setPropertyDerived(int propertyDerived) {
        this.propertyDerived = propertyDerived;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Теперь код выше успешно скомпилируется.

Этот подход называется [«Текучий интерфейс»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Тоже, наверное, не по теме :) А в C++ можно ли что-то подобное сделать (и есть ли у этого приема название)?

Comment: Название есть, только я его забыл :)
Про C++, к сожалению, не знаю

Comment: @pank, кажется, это называется «текучий интерфейс»

Comment: Классно! А как на деле можно использовать данную конструкцию? Будет интересно увидеть наглядно:)

Comment: @MikhailDedyukhin в ответе как раз это продемонстрировали. Установка свойств производного класса с помощью методов базового класса.

Comment: @pank, [вот статья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) по теме.

Comment: @MikhailDedyukhin, в [статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) есть немножко примеров, вкратце — удобное создание объекта в одну строчку с инициализацией  нужных свойств.

Comment: Написал аналогичный код на *C++*, но требуется явно указывать в шаблоне `Derived`, что не так удобно, как в *Java*. https://gist.github.com/psqq/2b7519c8d2b743f3b5bb72488bb3a28b

Comment: @pank, мне кажется, у меня получилось перенести, чтобы было так же удобно, как в Java: [ideone](http://ideone.com/UGt9i6).